# conflicting declaration of constexpr static struct class member

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, static, constexpr

I'm trying to declare a constexpr static struct array as a class member,but When i compile the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>

using namespace std;

typedef enum token_t {INTEGER,SIGN,EOE} token_t;

class Token{
        token_t type;
        int value;

        constexpr static struct token_d {
            token_t id;
            const char* name;

        } token_dump[] = {
            {INTEGER,"INTEGER"},
            {SIGN,"SIGN"},
            {EOE,"EOE"}
        };

    public:
        const char* get_token_type ();
        Token(token_t,int);
};

constexpr struct token_d Token::token_dump[];

const char* Token::get_token_type ()    {
    return token_dump[type].name;
};


Token::Token (token_t TokenType,int TokenValue) {
    type = TokenType;
    value = TokenValue;
};


int main()
{
    Token token1(INTEGER,2);
    cout<<token1.get_token_type();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
calc1.cpp:29:44: error: conflicting declaration ‘constexpr const token_d Token::token_dump []’
 constexpr struct token_d Token::token_dump[];
                                            ^
calc1.cpp:18:5: note: previous declaration as ‘constexpr const Token::token_d Token::token_dump [3]’
   } token_dump[] = {
     ^~~~~~~~~~
calc1.cpp:29:44: error: declaration of ‘constexpr const Token::token_d Token::token_dump [3]’ outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive]
 constexpr struct token_d Token::token_dump[];
```

How can i define token_dump[]? I can't figure it out.

> calc1.cpp:29:44: error: conflicting declaration ‘constexpr const
>   token_d Token::token_dump []’  constexpr struct token_d
>   Token::token_dump[];
>                                               ^ calc1.cpp:18:5: note: previous declaration as ‘constexpr const Token::token_d
>   Token::token_dump [3]’    } token_dump[] = {
>        ^~~~~~~~~~ calc1.cpp:29:44: error: declaration of ‘constexpr const Token::token_d Token::token_dump [3]’ outside of class is not
>   definition [-fpermissive]  constexpr struct token_d
>   Token::token_dump[];

Comment: You don't need to declare the static constexpr data member outside the class as you would with a non-constexpr one. You just define it inline as you did and remove the other declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant line of code should be:

```
constexpr Token::token_d Token::token_dump[];
```

When you defined `struct token_d` inside `class Token`, it means you are defining the struct `Token::token_d`, in other words it is scoped to that class. There is no name `token_d` at global scope.

When you write `struct token_d` at global scope, it declares `token_d` at global scope as a struct type, which is currently an incomplete type, and unrelated to `Token::token_d`.  Hence the type mismatch.

I would recommend not writing `struct T` to refer to a pre-existing `T` for exactly this reason (amongst others): if you are trying to refer to a pre-existing `T` but you made a mistake, it will declare a new incomplete type instead of giving an error in some situations.

---

Regarding the discussion about the need for an out-of-class definition for static class member variables:  C++17 is adding the concept of *inline variables*,  which is quite similar to inline functions in that you can define an inline variable in the header, and the compiler sorts it all out.  `constexpr` on a variable definition will imply `inline`. But prior to C++17 you still need to manually pick a translation unit to put an out-of-class definition in.

Comment: Ahh I thought static constexpr was a weird exception to the static rule before 17. I think I've used it in msvc before, but maybe that's not fully standard compliant.

Comment: @budjmt The definition is required if the variable is *odr-used* [which is complicated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). I believe there is no difference between `static const` and `static constexpr` with respect to odr-use, in C++14. But if a required definition is not present then it is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required - which means the compiler might happen to compile and link successfully anyway.

Comment: NB. There's a mistake on the page I linked to in my previous comment, it says " a violation of that is a link-time error." when in fact it is UB NDR which may or may not give a link error

Answer (score 0):

I just verified it in [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A48HKWe240Cj3fZW), (I wasn't 100% sure this would compile since you're using some C-style conventions) but all that's blocking this code is your second declaration of `token_dump`. `static constexpr` variables, like other `constexpr` variables, are defined inline. They ignore the normal class static requirements of being defined externally.

I couldn't get this code to compile in any of the online compilers below C++17. [This version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HPl11rt3pqJr0LTc) moves the declaration of token_dump into the get_token_type function. I don't know exactly why, but they can't locate the variable inside that function if it's in the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "You're using some C-style conventions" ?

Comment: OP code compiles correctly for me in C++11 mode with no changes other than removing the one offending line,  maybe you are using a buggy compiler.  Your suggested change doesn't really answer the question because this is about having a constexpr array defined in the class, not inside a member function

Comment: @MM Mostly the typedefs after naming the types (e.g. typedef enum token_t {} token_t;) and defining the struct inline with the static variable. I wasn't sure if defining the type inline to a static was allowed.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I've just been on wandbox using gcc and clang's latest versions, but I haven't checked otherwise. I realize that the version I linked doesn't even use the static solution, so I should probably fix that anyway.

Comment: Ah, I was compiling but not linking -- wandbox gives a link error. So perhaps your first paragraph is in fact incorrect prior to C++17 (otherwise there should not be a link error)